# Chromecast live duration

Tags: chromecast, live, duration, seek

I am playing a live content (SmoothStreaming) with a set duration in a Chromecast device. Although manifest has a parameter duration, Chromecast doesn't get it (duration: null).

I am trying do a seek to forward but Player only seek until 20 seconds later (buffering time).

Is there a way to set the duration of a live stream? Or Chromecast doesn't support live seeking?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK, this is not suppored As reported in this issues: [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36189877) and [2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36190845), it is stated that 
*"MPL does not support seeking for live Smooth Streaming streams. The feature is not feasible at the moment"*. Hope this helps.